# Metamask The method "signTypedData_v4" does not exist / is not available

Tags: metamask, javascript, signature

I am trying to use metamask with signedTypeDatav3 or v4. Their [docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#a-brief-history) say the latest protocol standards are supported but when I do the following I get an error "does not exist"

```js
 const signature = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "signTypedData_v4",
        params: [
          `To login you are signing to verify you are the owner of this address. Your one-time nonce is` +
            nonceFromServer,
          this.state.provider.selectedAddress,
        ],
      });
```

Error:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: The method "signTypedData_v4" does not exist / is not available. 
{ 
    code : -32601
    data: {origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}
    message: "The method \"signTypedData_v4\" does not exist / is not available."
}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```